# Ecto query function using pipe operator in Elixir

Tags: ecto, apache-phoenix

I am refactoring code for my app.

And I decided to change style of querying function with using `|>` in Elixir.

I have a query function to query `sales_items` by joining two different table `Item` and `Category`. And it works fine.

```
from(p in SalesItem, join: i in Item, on: p.item_id == i.id,
                     join: ca in Category, on: i.category_id == ca.id,     
                     where: p.sales_id == ^sales_id,
                     order_by: [desc: p.id]) |> Repo.all()
```

I changed above function like below with using pipe operator.

```
SalesItem
|> join(:inner, [s], i in Item, s.item_id == i.id)
|> join(:inner, [s, i], ca in Category, i.category_id == ca.id)
|> where([s, i, ca], s.sales_id == ^sales_id)
|> order_by([s, i, ca], [desc: s.id])
|> Repo.all()
```

However, the second function that I wrote with using pipe operator, triggers an error that `(undefined_column): column c1.category_id does not exist`

How can I resolve this issue?

-- Edit, add schemas

```
schema "sales_items" do
  field :item_total, :float, default: 0.0
  field :price, :integer
  field :quantity, :integer
  field :sales_id, Ecto.UUID
  field :item_id, Ecto.UUID
  field :user_id, Ecto.UUID
  field :has_attrs, :boolean, default: false
  timestamps()
end

schema "items" do
  field :active, :boolean, default: true
  field :deleted, :boolean, default: false
  field :price, :integer
  field :category_id, Ecto.UUID
  field :subcategory_id, Ecto.UUID
  field :sort_id, :integer
  timestamps()
end

schema "categories" do
  field :subcategory, :boolean, default: false
  field :sort_id, :integer
  field :active, :boolean, default: true
  timestamps()
end
```

Comment: Do you have a belongs_to, has_one, has_many, etc defined in any of your models? Most likely the cause of the error. You may post your schema here

Comment: I do not have any `belongs_to`, `has_one`, etc defined in my models. Can it be the cause of this error?

Comment: Do you see the db query log on your console? check the table that corresponds to c1. I suspect it's pointing to the categories table instead of the items table. Also, make sure the column category_id is in your migrations too (i.e it's in the database).